# cant get program to calculate correct factorial of a number

Tags: c, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I wrote a program to give the factorial of a number entered by the user. It is for an assignment and it must be written so the first function reads in a value  then passes it to the main then the main passes this to a second function which calculates the factorial of the number then prints it to the user. The problem is it keeps showing '1' as every number's factorial. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getValue()
{

    int n;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);

    return(n);
}

int factorial(int n)
{

    int i, f;

    f=1;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    f=f*i;

    printf("The factorial is: %d", f);

    return(f);
}

int main()
{

    int f;

    getValue();
    factorial(f);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You do not use the value returned from `getvalue()`

Comment: Isn't is passed into main when it is called?

Comment: No. Suppose the function returns the value `5`. Your main function behaves as if the statement `getValue();` is replaced with `5;`: the value is never used.

Comment: Ah right! so now how would I pass this value into my second function from the main?

Comment: Simply do `f = getValue();` which would behave as if you had written `f = 5;` Then the variable `f` gets assigned the value and you can use that value in other statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting `f` this should fix your problem:

```
int main()
{
    int f = getValue();
    factorial(f);

    return(0);
}
```

I am assuming that you have a typo in the code with the `scanf` since it would not compile otherwise but it should be:

```
scanf("%d%*c", &n);
            ^
```

Comment: I tried that now it doesn't print anything as the factorial? And yes sorry that was a typo

Comment: @user2147550 I updated my answer to be more specific and you can see it working here http://liveworkspace.org/code/2PteiA$7